# How to open Visual Studio Code with admin privileges to make effect of the installed extensions

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio-code

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and I have to download the C# extension for Visual Studio Code, once I installed it, It doesn't make effect. Then, vscode give me and advice that I should open vscode with admin privileges to make effect of the extensions installed, so I wrote on my terminal:

`sudo code .`

but it doesn't work, the terminal throws me:

`It is recommended to start vscode as a normal user. To run as root, you must specify an alternate user data directory with the --user-data-dir argument.`

but I don't know how to specify an alternate user data directory. I was searching how to do that in visual studio code docs but there is not a reference for this issue. If you know how to open with admin privileges in linux please help me.

Comment: When running as root this worked for me. ```code --user-data-dir="~/.vscode-root" --no-sandbox``` You can also add this to your .bashrc, .zshrc etc. to simplify it. Then you can just run vscode command from the terminal: ```alias vscode='code --user-data-dir="~/.vscode-root" --no-sandbox'```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To run with superuser:

```
$ sudo code --user-data-dir=~/root
```

By the way you will be able to run without setting params in the upcoming patch 1.5.0.

Comment: Do you know when this patch will be able to get it?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders - here you can already have a look, for beta version. VSCode now updates monthly, so the stable 1.5.0, around second week of September.

Comment: "You are trying to start Visual Studio Code as a super user which isn't recommended. If this was intended, please specify an alternate user data directory using the `--user-data-dir` argument"
Still waiting for that change in October 2020

Comment: for me doesn't works

Comment: When I run this command nothing happens

Comment: When I run this command nothing happens

Comment: This is not *really* [supported](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/131482#issuecomment-905198968).

Answer (score 15):

You can achieve this in either of following ways :

- Run vscode as ***superuser***: 
  `$ sudo code --user-data-dir=~/root` 
  This will open vscode without your previous settings (fresh) with superuser privileges and you can install your extensions.

**OR**

- Follow these steps :

1. `sudo chown -R <user> <path_to_your_vscode_installation_directory>`
2. Hit follwing in terminal 
   to check the current user on your machine : 
   `whoami` 
   for e.g. john
3. You can find path of vscode directory using following command : 
   `whereis code`
   e.g. in my case path is : ****/usr/share/code****
4. Now run : 
   `sudo chown -R john /usr/share/code` 
   This will run vscode with admin privilege
5. Now install your extensions
6. After reset owner back to ***root*** 
   `sudo chown -R root /usr/share/code`

Comment: what about macos `sudo code --user-data-dir=~/root` is not working ?

Answer (score 7):

My simple solution is:

```
sudo code --verbose --user-data-dir --no-sandbox
```

(not as root but as sodoer user)

Comment: If working with docker containers it takes away priviledges from a user that docker-compose is set up to. In that case adding yourself to a group with rights is a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in visual studio code and type:

```
shell command
```

and press "install" in the `PATH`.

Then in your terminal go to the folder that you want to open and type "code ." It'll open the project in visual studio code as root.

Comment: What is Cmd key?

Answer (score 1):

To able to run vs code as superuser:
open code file with a text editor

> sudo nano /usr/bin/code

then comment on the following line of codes :

```
if [ "$(id -u)" = "0" ]; then
    for i in "$@"
    do
        case "$i" in
            --user-data-dir | --user-data-dir=* | --file-write )
                CAN_LAUNCH_AS_ROOT=1
            ;;
        esac
    done
    if [ -z $CAN_LAUNCH_AS_ROOT ]; then
        echo "You are trying to start Visual Studio Code as a super user which isn't recommended. If this was intended, please specify an alternate user data directory using the \`--user-data-dir\` argument." 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

to

```
#if [ "$(id -u)" = "0" ]; then
#   for i in "$@"
#   do
#       case "$i" in
#           --user-data-dir | --user-data-dir=* | --file-write )
#               CAN_LAUNCH_AS_ROOT=1
#           ;;
#       esac
#   done
#   if [ -z $CAN_LAUNCH_AS_ROOT ]; then
#       echo "You are trying to start Visual Studio Code as a super user which isn't recommended. If this was intended, please specify an alternate user data directory using the \`--user-data-dir\` argument." 1>&2
#       exit 1
#   fi
#fi
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It does not solve my problem, but at least sheds more light into it.

Comment: This doesn't resolve. The message obviously doesn't appears but code don't starts

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in OpenSuse tumbleweed, I performed a couple of extra steps:

1. I needed to invoke sudo telling it to preserve the environment as vscode (X11 really) needs to know the value of the DISPLAY environment variable.
2. I wanted to reuse my existing data dir and installed extensions.

```
sudo -E code --user-data-dir=$HOME/.config/Code --extensions-dir=$HOME/.vscode/extensions
```

After I am done with my editing / debugging session, I needed to reset the permissions of the data dir and extensions, like so:

```
sudo chown -R your-user:your-group $HOME/.config/Code $HOME/.vscode/extensions
```

Where `your-user` and `your-group` correspond to your uid/gid which you can obtain from the `id` command.

Answer (score 0):

here's a step-by-step solution on how to resolve the error "You are trying to start Visual Studio Code as a super user which isn't recommended" when upgrading VS Code in the terminal:

1. Open a terminal window and navigate to the directory where the VS Code executable is located.
2. Run the command:`code --no-sandbox --user-data-dir=/my/custom/data/dir` .
   This will start VS Code without the sandbox and use the specified directory for user data.

Answer (score 0):

Running vscode as root stop working (they removed `--no-sandbox` option)
[https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_59#_progress-for-electron-sandbox-support]
[https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146445]

If you just want to browse, view and edit 'root' owned directory tree (/etc/, /var/lib/, ...) as root using  vscode, you can do via `Remote - SSH` vscode extension.
Just connect to your localhost as root via ssh (you need sshd service running):
In short:

1. Edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
Match Address 127.0.0.1
    PermitRootLogin yes
```

2. Execute:

```
# generate ssh private key if you don't have. In my case it's RSA key.

sudo sh -c "cat /home/YOUR_USER/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys"
sudo systemctl restart ssh

# Test that you can connect:
ssh root@localhost
```

3. Connect to your localhost via "Remote Explorer" in vs code.

[https://ponteshare.ch/2022/01/vscode-remote-ssh-as-root/]

Answer (score 0):

I had a normal VS Code profile running under default user (not sudo).
My purpose was to run VS Code as Superuser and save downloaded extensions and another settings from my previous profile.

One more problem was that proxy settings did not save, when I'd run VS code with sudo.

So what I'd needed:

- change an extensions folder;
- change a user data folder;
- change proxy settings (magically they worked when run under default user, and not worked under Superuser).

So I changed a command line to a program in shortcut this way:

```
sudo /usr/share/code/code --extensions-dir="/home/user_name/.vscode/extensions/" --user-data-dir="/home/user_name/.config/Code/" --no-sandbox --unity-launch %F
```

and set up proxy parameters in a settings file:

```
"http.proxy": "http://squid.my_proxy.com:1234",
"http.proxySupport": "on",
"http.proxyStrictSSL": false
```

Settings file has path:

```
/home/user_name/.config/Code/User/settings.json
```