# VS Code extension installation without admin rights

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am thinking of asking my IT-Department of gaining the right to install VS-Studio Code, and using it with some extensions. Like Python.
My Question is: Can I install the extensions without having to use an admin user, under windows?
I got this exact Problem with Notepad++, where i can only install the Editor, via the Software deployment tool, but not the extensions(via the editor myself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the latest VS Code revision 1.26 (currently 1.25 insiders) it will be possible to install VS Code as a User and also updating all the extensions inside this directory.

See this link [VS Code 1.25 release Notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_25#_user-setup-for-windows)

Answer (score 6):

You have the option to unpack the zip file and use the editor without running the installer. You will lack some features like 'Open with Code' in the contextmenu of the file explorer.

[Windows setup without installer](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows#_trouble-with-the-installer)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer **No** for installing VSCode and **~yes** for installing extensions.

You seem to assume VSCode would install without admin privileges however that is not the case. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/534) since 2015 with a feature request to allow user level installations. There is another known [bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10783) which would prevent VSCode from launching without an admin account after an update.

To answer your question about installing an extension, it would depend on extension and if you've write access to your path for installing extensions which defaults to

```
%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions
```

A lot of extensions seem to require root access under [Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938887/how-to-open-visual-studio-code-with-admin-privileges-to-make-effect-of-the-insta), however on Windows most of the extensions install without any admin privileges ever since 1.0 release.

(Let me admit I now use VSCode as my primary editor and have stopped playing around all those icon packs & themes which used to require admin rights almost always so maybe it has nothing to do with post 1.0 releases).

Comment: As far as I understand, it would be a corporate nightmare to use vscode, which i would only install once with admin rights. Because i would not really be able to install extensions, or even the normal update every month.

Comment: It seems that C++ Intellisense 1.16.1 extension cannot work in VSCode-1.22.2 without *execution* rights in `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions` under Windows.  In our site i had to use `--extensionHomePath` to change this folder's location.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue in a restricted environment and got it to work
Use this link : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs?dv=win it downloads an executable with 'User' in the name
ex: In my case it was: VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.68.0.exe your major and minor versions might be greater if you see this a few moons after now.

On installing this installs inside my user folder - AppData folder. Kudos to MSFT, rest is all under user control and no elevated admin right necessary!